# Can I always replace do ... pure ... with ado ... in ... in Purescript?

Tags: typeclass, purescript, do-notation

Can I always replace a do-block like this:

```
do
  ...
  pure ...
```

where the last line is "pure" something,
with an ado-block like this:

```
ado
  ...
  in ...
```

?

I know `do` only requires `Bind` and not `Monad` (i.e. `Applicative`), but we're already using `pure` so we're already `Applicative`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The long answer

The difference between Applicative (and therefore applicative do - `ado`) and Monad (`bind` or `do`) is that when combining two applicative computations, the second one cannot depend on the result of the first computation. This means:

```
do
  x <- getX
  y <- getY
  pure { x, y }
-- Can be turned into
ado
  x <- getX
  y <- getY
  in { x, y }
```

But if y depends on x we cannot do that:

```
do
  x <- getX
  y <- getY x
  pure { x, y }
-- This won't compile
ado
  x <- getX
  y <- getY x
  in { x, y }
```

This means the answer to your question is "no".

### Examples

Let's think about an intuitive example. The Aff Monad allows us to run asynchronous effects, like fetching data from an API. If the requests are independent, we can run them in parallel.

```
ado
  user1 <- get "/user/1"
  user2 <- get "/user/2"
  in [user1, user2]
```

If they depend on each other, we need to run one request after another:

```
do
  user1 <- get "/user/1"
  bestFriend <- get ("/user/" <> user1.bestFriendId)
  pure { user1, bestFriend }
```

Please note, that `Aff` always runs things sequentially no matter if you use `bind` or `apply`, unless we use `parallel` which turns an `Aff` into a `ParAff`. Notice the lack of a Bind/Monad instance for `ParAff` because two parallel computations cannot depend on each others results! https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-aff/7.1.0/docs/Effect.Aff#t:ParAff

Meaning for the first example to really run in parallel, we have to actually

```
ado
  user1 <- parallel $ get "/user/1"
  user2 <- parallel $ get "/user/2"
  in [user1, user2]
```

Another example I like is parsing/validation. Imagine you are parsing two fields of user input: A date string and an age. We can check both properties an parallel and return two errors if both properties are invalid. But to validate a date, we might first have to check if an input value is a string *and then* check if the value is a date string. For an example library, check out [purescript-foreign](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-foreign/7.0.0)

```
validated = ado
  date <- do
    str <- isString dateInput
    isDate date
  age <- do
    int <- isInt ageInput
    isPositive int
  in { date, age }
```

We see that Applicative is much weaker than Monad. But there are intances, where forgoing in the power of Monad can give us other interesting possibilities like parallelisation or multiple errors.

Comment: Given your first heading, I expected there to be a short answer somewhere as well :-)

Comment: There was a short answer @Bergi: it was "no" :-)